# Distinguish whether time series comes from or another Poisson process

Tags: hypothesis-testing, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I have a time series of binary events, where the events are drawn from a Poisson process with a 50% chance of having a rate of $\lambda_1$ and a 50% change of having a rate of $\lambda_2$. Here $\lambda_1\approx10\times\lambda_2$. My goal is to distinguish between the two in as minimal a total time as possible.

The simplest solution would be to simply set a threshold in the total number of measured events, and if the number is less than the threshold, classify the rate as $\lambda_2$, and if the number is greater than the threshold, classify the rate as $\lambda_1$. However, doing so requires long time measurements so the two distributions sufficiently separate. I am wondering if there is any other information that can be gleaned from short time-series data which can help distinguish them, or what test statistic might be used for hypothesis testing besides just their total sum.

Comment: Do you want to minimize the total time, as stated, or the *expected* total time? // Do you know the $\lambda_i$ or do you assume only that $\lambda_1=10\lambda_2$?

Comment: Minimize expected time I believe. In reality, I will be reading in these time series in real time, and as soon as they pass some classification threshold (where I can say they either belong to rate 1 or to rate 2) I will stop reading in the data.

I do not know a precise value for $\lambda_1$, but it is roughly O(1) (in some units of time), and $\lambda_2$ is then $\approx 10\times\lambda_1$.

Comment: When you have a clear idea of the $\lambda_i,$ this is solved with the [SPRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_probability_ratio_test).  Variants have been developed for unknown $\lambda_i.$